# What is the C# equivalent code for the Powershell sript to remove user from Adminstrators group?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, active-directory

I have a PowerShell script. It is to remove the user from the Administrators group. It's working fine for local and domain users both.

```
Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "Admin02"
```

I want to implement this in C#. I have tried the below code. But it's not working for the domain account.

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, args[0]);
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "Administrators");

    if (user != null && group != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (group.Members.Remove(user))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User successfully removed from Local Administrators.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User is not a Local Administrator1.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User is not a Local Administrator.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User was not found.");
    }
}
```

Its printing User was not found.

I have tried with `ContextType.Domain` as well.

**Edit**: Thank you @Gabriel Luci. for providing the solution. I tried his solution, but there is a challenge with it.

I have a domain user name T1/spreda (forward slash).

[image]

But when I run your code and see the value of member, it shows users like this (with back slash). I have written this code to check the user.

```
var group = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./Administrators");
                
foreach (var m in (IEnumerable)group.Invoke("Members"))
{
    var member = new DirectoryEntry(m);
    var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    //if (str.Contains(args[0]))
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("Found");
    //    var returnVal = group.Invoke("Remove", new[] { member.Path });
    //    Console.WriteLine(returnVal.ToString());
    //    break;
```

So Is there a way to handle this?

[image]

Comment: `IdentityType.Name` is the common name for the object, which is unique within the domain. Use `IdentityType.SamAccountName` to match by username.

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ I chnaged, Now `group.Members.Remove(user)` is returing `false`

Comment: Try to remove it this way `group.Members.Remove(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Admin02");` and do not forget to save the changes with `group.Save();`

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ `group.Members.Remove(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Admin02");` is also returning `false`

Comment: have you try my solution in (your same question) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559291/how-to-remove-domain-user-from-administrators-group-using-c/75564367#75564367 ?

Comment: @tuyau2poil its not working as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using the `AccountManagement` namespace for this (`GroupPrincipal`/`UserPrincipal`) is that the act of creating the object loads all the properties. That means that it needs to connect to AD to create a `UserPrincipal` object of an AD user, but we don't need to to do that to remove a user from a group.

You can do this with `DirectoryEntry`, which `GroupPrincipal` and `UserPrincipal` use behind the scenes anyway. It would look like this:

```
var group = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./Administrators");

foreach (var m in (IEnumerable)group.Invoke("Members"))
{
    var member = new DirectoryEntry(m);
    if (member.Name == args[0]) {
        group.Invoke("Remove", new [] {member.Path});
        break;
    }
}
```

This uses the [WinNT provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/adsi-winnt-provider) (as opposed to LDAP) to load the local group. The `.` means the local computer. If you wanted to load the Administrators group from a remote computer, you can put the computer name in the path, like `WinNT://computer1/Administrators`.

`DirectoryEntry` is a wrapper around the native Windows C++ COM ADSI objects. In this case, because we're loading a group, it's an [`IADsGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsgroup) object. We use [`DirectoryEntry.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invoke) to call a method from the underlying object. So `group.Invoke("Members")` calls [`IADsGroup::Members`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsgroup-members), which returns a list of the members. Likewise, `group.Invoke("Remove", new [] {member.Path})` calls [`IADsGroup::Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsgroup-remove) to remove the member.

I always prefer using `DirectoryEntry`, even when working purely with AD objects. It gives you far more control over performance. I talked about that in an article I wrote: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I’ll try this ne update you. One quick question, will it also work on nonenglish systems as well? If they have different language in their systems? Also is there a way to check if a given user is domain user using DirectoryEntry?

Comment: This code will work regardless of if the user is a domain user or local user. For a non-English system, I think the only thing that might be different is the name of the Administrators group. You can change that to the translated name of the group.

Comment: Please refer this comment.  Why I’m asking this question to check for a domain user because I already have a code in production which works as expected for a local user to remove from administrators group and I don’t want to impact that. So I can add a check if a user is a domain user then consider your code else the existing code, which is already tested

Comment: But I am running this code on 10000 machines and so is there a way to know what would be the the translated name on each machine? I mean is there a way to know the locale and get the equivalent translation of administrators?

Comment: There is a `GetLocalizedAdministratorGroupName` method in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120998/1202807

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to use different code for local vs. domain. It's easier to use the same code for both rather than trying to figure out if it's a domain user and run different code. You're going to have to change your existing code no matter what you do. But if you really want to check, look at `member.Path`. A local user will have the computer name. A domain user will have the domain name.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your solution, but I am facing some issues with it. I have updated in the question. Please refer the **Edit**

Comment: The forward slash is just how the domain and username are separated in a WinNT path (since a forward slash is what separates all parts, much like a URL). Why is that a problem?

Comment: problem is that it's not going inside `if (member.Name == args[0]) {`

Comment: I was assuming that `args[0]` was just the username, since `member.Name` is just the username (no domain name). If it includes the domain, then you'll have to do some string manipulation before you compare.

Comment: understood, could you suggest a good way for manipulation? I mean if the username is passed like T1\spreda then with which property shall I compare with?

Comment: Replace the ``\`` with `/` and look for it in `member.Path`

Comment: Although its removing the user, but `Invoke` method is returning `null`, may I know why? what are different return value in case of success/failure?

Comment: That's normal. If there was an error, it would throw an exception. The exceptions it might throw are in the [documentation for `DirectoryEntry.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invoke)